# Corollary of Mantel theorem

Tags: graph-theory

Deduce from the proof of Mantel theorem the following strengthening of the assertion. Let G be a triangle-free graph of order n. Then $e(G)  \leq   n^2/4$, with equality if and only if G is a complete bipartite graph $ K_{n/2,n/2} $

This is how Mantel's theorem is proved in my textbook:

Let G be a triangle-free graph of order n. Then $\Gamma (x) \cap \Gamma (y) = \phi$ for every edge $xy \in E(G)$, so

$d(x)+d(y)\leq n$

Summing these inequalities for all $e(G)$ edges $xy$, we find that $\sum_{x\in G} d(x)^2 \leq n\space e(G). $

Now since the sum of the degrees is twice the number of the edges then by Cauchy's inequality we have, $ (2 \space e(G))^2 = (\sum_{x\in G} d(x))^2 \leq n \space (\sum_{x\in G} d(x)^2)$ Hence $(2e(G))^2 \leq n^2e(G)$

implying $e(G) \leq n^2/4$

I am not quite sure how to start. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $K_{n/2,n/2}$ only makes sense if $n$ ils even. In general you want $K_{\lceil n/2\rceil,\lfloor n/2\rfloor}$.

Comment: I guess "deduce from the proof" is your hint. So you would start by looking at the proof of Mantel's theorem. As the proof can be proved in different styles, it would be easier for us to help you if we know what your proof looks like. So why don't you edit your question to include an outline of your proof of Mantel's theorem?

Comment: I added the proof of Mantel theorem from my textbook

Comment: Since $G$ is triangle-free we know that $\Gamma(x)$ is an independent set, right? Now, assuming that the inequality $d(x)+d(y)\le n$ is actually an equality for every edge $xy$, can you show that $V\setminus\Gamma(x)$ is also an independent set, and therefore $G$ is a bipartite graph?